# Overlapping colliders with Rayacast and mouseClick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 5 gameobjects on my scene, all having a collider attached to it.

Now I don't know why - but my first top layer (a starBtn) sometimes fail to detect a mouseClick?

It's in 2d.

I detect all raycastHits and store the hits in an array - I then check all layers of all of them and return the one at the top layer. The one I need to call anaction/function from. My top layer is a square sprite.

Is there a best practice for this or a way to ingnore a collider area if an object in from of it is overlapping?

Cheers

Ps: I willadd code to this question in an hour or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. What I had to do to solve this was to add a z-value to each object with a collider. 
Then cycle through each objects' z-value - storing the highest value. Although this is 2d.